# Frigidaire FEX831FS4 washer dripping water after fixing agitator. How to find and fix leak?

Tags: repair, washing-machine

The washer was not leaking any water before I fixed the agitator. Now [agitator works fine](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/166756/besides-welding-are-there-other-ways-to-connect-this-gear-to-its-axle), but some water drips on top of transmission.

So I am backtracking the work I did to understand what is causing the water leak. Here is what I remember:

1. Since washer was rusty, I was not able to separate the washer outer tub from the transmissions's shaft on which the agitator goes on. So I gave up and took upper half of transmission with the outer tub to a welder to fix it. See picture to understand how far I was able to disassemble washer:

[image]

2. I also partially pulled off the drive block (or maybe even whole inner shaft with drive block) and was not quite able to get it back to the original position. See this picture:

[image]

Here is a diagram of my FEX831FS4 washing machine:

[image]

**The questions I have are:**

1. Since I did not separate transmission from outer tub, then is it likely that part #16 (the tub seal) is actually fine? Perhaps I pried something a little too deep with screwdriver? Could it be that all the gunk collected these years was preventing the leak from happening? Maybe I can just refill it with gasket maker in place where I pried with screwdriver?
2. Is it possible that the water comes down through the agitator shaft through the gap that I introduced by forcing up the drive block?
3. Just wondering, would something like ATP-205 rejuvenate seals if they were damaged? That liquid kinda work for gaskets in car. Though toxicity and getting dirty clothes because of that fluid is another concern why I would prefer to double check with folks that have experience fixing appliances.

This is old washer and I want to extend its life a little bit before getting a new one on Black Friday sale.

Comment: Not sure how you could locate where it is coming from exactly. Maybe if you can get under it while running to see where the leak may be coming from, but with stuff in the way, it may be to hard.

Comment: @JeffCates The leak appears to have stopped on its own after a week or so. Will keep an eye for few more days. I am wondering if new gunk (lint and detergent) somehow replaced the old gunk that I scrapped out and clogged back things.